# How can I create a date range picker with jquery UI datepicker?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to create a date range picker. I need the date picker to open in a modal window and then be able to select dates between a specified date range. Is there a way to do this using the jquery UI datepicker and bootstrap?

Thanks

Comment: Please try out jquery UI https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: Your question title says not using any plugins or widgets, then your question asks about using jQuery datepicker? Which by the way is part of jQuery UI not the core jQuery as @Shiladitya mentions.

Comment: The answer is "Yes". It is possible to develop own datatimepicker using javascript only. Please read [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting a good answer.